# How can I rotate an image and move it to a specific location?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to upload a picture and then rotate it and move it to specific location, but I can't seem to get it to rotate. I have this code because I want to save the picture with the document.

```
Sub tyh()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture _
    Filename:="C:\Users\dovi.dovi-PC\Desktop\ads bh\IMG-7042.jpg", _
    linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
    Left:=1200, Top:=0, Width:=350, Height:=604
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The macro recorder would really help you here - upload the picture and see what code it produces for the rotating. Mine is like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementRotation 90
```

Of course, the `Selection` and the `ActiveSheet~.Select`  should be avoided, but this depends on your code. This is a good way to rotate the picture without select:

```
Sub TestMe()

    KillAllShapes Worksheets(1)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Pictures.Insert ("C:\SomePic.jpg")
    Dim myShape As Shape
    Set myShape = Worksheets(1).Shapes(1)

    With myShape
        .Top = Range("B5").Top
        .Left = Range("B5").Left
        .IncrementRotation 180 'or 90
    End With

End Sub

Sub KillAllShapes(wks As Worksheet)

    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In wks.Shapes
        sh.Delete
    Next

End Sub
```

This one from [the ShapeRange.IncrementRotation documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shaperange.incrementrotation) looks ok:

```
Set myDocument = Worksheets(1) 
With myDocument.Shapes(1).Duplicate 
    .Fill.PresetTextured msoTextureGranite 
    .IncrementLeft 70 
    .IncrementTop -50 
    .IncrementRotation 30 
End With
```

Comment: i tried that but how do i implement that into such code mine allways comes out as error

Comment: @zgivod - you recorded a macro and there was an error when you ran it? The code above would throw an  error, if your Picture is not named exactly "Picture 1".

Comment: if i use the exact recorded macro then i wont be able to save picture with document....

Comment: @zgivod - I really do not understand what do you mean with "exact recorded macro and saving picture with document"... Honestly, the macro recorder is one of the few things that gives some small advantage of VBA. Anyway, just COPY and PASTE the second code in my answer, changing the path `"C:\SomePic.jpg"` to where the picture is. The code would delete all other pictures on the first worksheet, so be careful. Cheers!